# How to put string with different names into Object with for loop

Tags: java, json, mongodb, jsp, for-loop

I want to put each posts that stored in JsonPost String array into Object with different names. the code i have tried with is as follows.

```
String[] JsonPost = request.getParameterValues("post[]");

    BasicDBObject postObj = new BasicDBObject();
        for(String str : JsonPost){

        postObj.put(str, str);

        }
    System.out.println(postObj);
```

for example, if JsonPost = ["Apple","Orange"]

i am getting output as follows.

```
 { "Apple" : [ "Apple"] , "Orange" : [ "Apple" , "Orange"]}
```

but i want to get output as follows.

```
{ "Apple" : [ "Apple"] , "Orange" : ["Orange"]}
```

plese help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you post your BasicDBObject class? Likely the problem is there. Also, as a side note, java variable names are conventionally lowercase, so it may be preferable to change "JsonPost" to "jsonPost" to avoid confusion with class names.

Comment: BasicDBObject is an object which is used in MongoDB. Just consider this as an Object.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with your jsonPost object, I just tried this:

```
    String[] jsonPost = new String[] { "Apple", "Orange" };

    BasicDBObject postObj = new BasicDBObject();
    for (String str : jsonPost) {

        postObj.put(str, str);

    }
    System.out.println(postObj);
```

And the output was:

```
{ "Apple" : "Apple" , "Orange" : "Orange"}
```

Can you print jsonPost?

Comment: Yes I can Print jsonPost. but in my case, i am assigning request.getParameterValues("post[]"); by capturing from request.                 I am confused with  new String[] { "Apple", "Orange" };  please help me.